# Should we have an off-topic chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

Our "sister" site, Code Golf and Coding Challenges, decided to create an [off-topic chatroom](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24680/should-we-make-a-room-for-tnbs-off-topic-discussions) to complement their main one. Should we do the same thing, and if so what should it be named?

Answer (score 8):

### Not yet

If we start getting lots of off topic noise maybe

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

Before we get clutter lets make a place for that clutter (and a place to tell ppl to go)

Answer (score -1):

## Name: The Garbage Disposal

Suggested by Adám [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63586429#63586429).